# How to type annotate a function with return "shape" based on input "shape"?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

The function below receives a instance of a type (e.g. `int`) and returns a instance of another type (e.g. `str`).

But, it may receive list of the input type (`list[int]`), and returns a list of the output type in that case (`list[str]`).

The way I found to achieve that is to use `Union`:

```py
from typing import Union

def foo(a: Union[int, list[int]]) -> Union[str, list[str]]:
   ...
```

But the type checker fails when I use it in another function:

```py
def bar(s: str):
   """this function should receive a single `str`"""
   ...

b = bar(foo(33)) # type checks fails: Type "str | list[str]" cannot be assigned to type "str"
```

The warning raise by the type checker is:

`"Type "str | list[str]" cannot be assigned to type "str""`

The `int` and `str` types are just for examples. They could be other classes.

How do I type annotate the first function to not get a fail?

i.e., how to annotate the input and return so the return type is based on the "shape" of the input type?

(So the type checker could know that the return type would be a single `str` in that example)

Comment: Use `@overload` to define the two different cases.

Comment: @Barmar. Thank you! If you. If you answer. I'll mark as resolved.

Comment: Why not just actually write two different functions? It seems clear that this function is being expected to do two completely different things: compute a str based on an int, and compute a list of str based on a list of int.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, you're right. But I'm working with existing code that does all process in a single function and expects that input and output types, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=overload#typing.overload). Try the following:

```py
from typing import overload, Union

@overload
def foo(a: list[int]) -> list[str]:
    ...
@overload
def foo(a: int) -> str:
    ...
def foo(a: Union[int, list[int]]) -> Union[str, list[str]]:
    # implementation goes here. it could be something like the following
    if isinstance(a, int):
        return str(a)
    # since we already checked if a was an int, it must be a list from here on
    return [str(elm) for elm in a]
```

Basically, this tells the type checker that if it sees a call to `foo` with a `list[int]` param, the return will be of type `list[str]`, and likewise for `int` in and `str` out. In your original formulation, the best the type checker can determine is that all combinations of in and out types are possible.

By the way, the modern way to express `Union` is with a pipe (`|`). This syntax was introduced in [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/) and is available in python 3.10 and beyond. We can rewrite your implementation signature more succinctly as

```py
def foo(a: int | list[int]) -> str | list[str]:
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example code you have provided, you declared that `foo` returns `str | list[str]`, but you have declared that `bar` only accepts `str`. You are receiving this error because your code doesn't answer the question: "*What happens if `foo` returns `list[str]`?*".

However, if you know that `foo` is going to return `str` in this specific case, then you can utilize `cast()` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)):

```py
from typing import cast

b = bar(cast(str, foo(33)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. But in this case the `@overload` is a better option, because `cast` would go on the "client" code that uses the function, and I can not modify the client code in my case.